# How to generate model classes in python from sqlite3 file

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I want to generate the model for my application from a .sqlite3 file. Is there a quick and painless way to scaffold the file and generate automatically the classes from the tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/) management command for this:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Note you need to tell django which database it should use by specify `DATABASES` setting.